# When will GCC/LLVM based languages support SEH exceptions on x86 windows?

Tags: gcc, exception, llvm

I've heard that the only reason why GCC and LLVM based compilers don't use SEH for exception handling on x86 windows is that it is patented by Borland. SEH exception handling has been implemented for x64 windows for a long time now. Also google told me that the patent will expire in 2014. Is there any official plans for implementing SEH-based exceptions with GCC and LLVM teams?

Comment: I'm gonna question whether or not this is on-topic, it's pretty specific to a moment in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been discussions of technical details and some patches proposed for LLVM (for supporting infrastructure, but not the final, encumbered backend piece), so it is likely that the final pieces will be implemented fairly quickly after the legal issues pass.

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.devel/69945